# Values from javascript to SQL Query

Tags: javascript, sql, apex

I have an interactive report on APEX. I need to update the rows that are selected by the checkbox so I've added

```
apex_item.checkbox(1,id,'UNCHECKED') " ",
```

Now to get the values from the checkbox I use

```
var id_s= $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

En fact, if I try console.log(id_s) I can see the values which are those that I need to do my second query

I call this function when I click on a button (Dynamic Action)

My question is: how can I pass now these values that I get from the JS
to my SQL QUERY -> UPDATE x set y where id IN (,,,,)

Thank you

**FIXED,
I've created a PROCESS,**

check this question
[apex checkbox to pl sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341732/apex-checkbox-to-pl-sql)

Comment: Step 1 - given that using javascript instead of simply posting the form represents a quantum leap in complexity, justify doing so.

Comment: Well, I have this function onclick that returns the checkbox selected
How can I pass these values to a query, using Dynamic Action?

Comment: @DanBracuk fixed, thank you :)